# How to change window.rootViewController in React Native?

Tags: ios, facebook, react-native, nswindow

It's easy to change `window.rootViewController` in pure iOS programming.

In pure iOS programming, when user login successfully, I used to change the `rootViewController`.

But how can I change `rootViewController` in React Native?

Or some other ways to reach my goal?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Why exactly you want to change the rootViewController? You just build all your views including the login screen as components in react native and then use render logic to display the component you actually want to show for the given state (e.g. user logged in or not).

Comment: I know it's a solution, and many people did. But I still want to know how

Comment: Me too curious about it

Comment: react native code push shows a white screen (that default color) when updating so the quickest solutionn is to display a the same acolor as the slashscreen